# Date time returns 0 in FIREBUG for getDateFromFormat function

Tags: javascript, date

```
var startDate = getDateFromFormat("27/09/2012 12:00 AM", "dd/mm/yy hh:mm tt");
```

The above code sets `startDate` to 0 in FireBug when I should be getting the `DateTime` in the format specified above.

Date Time format cannot change.
Can you tell me what I can do to get the datetime as specified.

Comment: How do you mean "returns"? It should set startDate to something, but a `var` statement doesn't have a return value.

Comment: Looks like getDateFromFormat isn't defined. Define it with a function that does what you want.

Comment: Google for the function name and you will find the code you need to include. http://mattkruse.com/javascript/date/compact_source.html - but you might want to consider using datejs instead of some obscure parser.